# Style a banner card | HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

How do you make the `position: absolute;` `position: relative;` stay together but have an auto height

I am trying to make profile cards in the style of Discord (latest design). When trying to show both the banner and a banner color it isn't aligned correctly. If anyone could help me, please?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7qxV.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCOED.png)

To debug I tried to use CSS data selectors `(\[data-??='true'\])`

```css
.preview-card.pfp[data-prem='True'] img {
  top: 85px;
}
.preview-card .pfp[data-prem='False'] img {
  top: 50px;
}
```

Yesm this will work but not for everything.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If an issue is resolved, please post it as an answer or mark the answer that resolved your issue. :)

Comment: how do i mark it as resolved? sorry this is my first post so not use to this platform yet

Comment: @btech205 You are supposed to click on the '✔️' under the votes from an answer. You are not supposed to post an answer saying `It's resolved.` But instead post an answer explaining how you fixed it, using a snippet as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a space missing. Try this maybe:

```
.preview-card .pfp[data-prem='True'] img {
  top: 85px;
}
.preview-card .pfp[data-prem='False'] img {
  top: 50px;
}
```